# Cant print out my function calculation

Tags: c

My task is to take someones who won a jackpot of 1m dollar, put it in the bank and earns 8% yearly rate on his money. Now, before every year ends he pulls 100k. So how many years it will take him to empty his account?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
long int year_ended(long int prize);//declare the function to be implemented 


int main(void)

{

    long int jackpot, years;

    jackpot = 1000000;

    for (years = 0; jackpot >= 0; years++) //counting the years until the jackpot is 0
        year_ended(jackpot); 

    printf("it will take %ld years to empty the account", years);

    return 0;
}

long int year_ended(long int prize) //function to decrement 100k every year and add the erned interest

{
    double yearlyRate = 0.08;

    int YearlyWithdraws = 100000, left;

    left = (prize - YearlyWithdraws) * yearlyRate + (prize - YearlyWithdraws);

    prize = left;

    return prize;
}
```

The error is: the program keeps running, but i get no output..

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please describe the error you get. Compiler/syntax error? Logic error?

Comment: Sorry you totally right, just edited. @phimuemue

Comment: You got an infinite `for` loop because `jackpot` is always the same value. In C, function parameters are *by value*, so when you exit a function, any parameters you modified inside the function is reset.

Comment: thank you, your comment was very helpful @ m0skit0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (years = 0; jackpot >= 0; years++)
    year_ended(jackpot);
```

This is an infinite loop as the condition is always true. You probably want to modify `jackpot`. Something like:

```
for (years = 0; jackpot >= 0; years++) 
    jackpot = year_ended(jackpot);
```

Comment: And print `jackpot` as well, not `years` ;)

Comment: Printing `jackpot` will give a value less than or equal to 0. Not sure if that's what OP wanted. Because he's calculating the years taken.

Comment: thank allot! now i understand my error :), appreciate it @KingsIndian